# how to fetch column data from sql database Table and put that data into string in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cakephp

I am trying a lot but nothing work for me.

My query is that how to fetch column data from sql database Table and put that data into an string in PHP?

Please check What I am doing.

I have the table "DriveRegisterTable" in which 4 columns in database table, 1st "id" 2nd "username" 3rd "txtMail" 4th "rxtMail" .

Now I want to select txtMail and rxtMail from database table where username = "John"

Now in my database table "username" john have txtMail is " johnery99@gmail.com"  and rxtMail is "sarah88@gmail.com"

Now I want to fetch these thing on my php string.

Now I want to select txtMail and rxtMail from database table where username = "John" and put txtMail and rxtMail values which are johnery99@gmail.com and sarah88@gmail.com in PHP String and then send the mail.

Please check what I am doing it is not working for me:

```
<?php


$db_host  = "localhost";
$username = "jacktask";
$db_pass  = "sormor4455";
$database = "myDatabaseDB";

mysql_connect("$db_host", "$username", "$db_pass");

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find database4");

$txt_username          = $_REQUEST['txt_username']; // here user name is John


$query  = mysql_query("SELECT txt_email,rxt_email FROM DriveRegisterTable WHERE txt_username ='$txt_username'");


//$sql = "SELECT txt_email,rxt_email FROM DriveRegisterTable WHERE txt_username ='$txt_username' ORDER BY id ";
$res = mysql_query($query);


if($query){    // Dont know how to send mail or what to write in this condition block


$to      = $txt_Mail;      // want johnery99@gmail.com here only but not able to fetch this mail here
$subject = 'Hello Subject!';
$message = 'Hi';
$headers = 'From: $txt_email' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: txt_email' . "\r\n" .        // want sarah88@gmail.com here but txt_email does not give any value here means sarah88@gmail.com
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}


mysql_close();

?>
```

I just want to select johnery99@gmail.com and sarah88@gmail.com from John and send mail.

Any Idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: Are you really using CakePHP..?

Comment: If you're using CakePHP, **do not** use `mysql_query` under any circumstances. If this application is on the public internet it's vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) because of what you've done here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre going to loop through your query

also your $res is redundant, its better to remove that

```
if($query){    // Dont know how to send mail or what to write in this condition block

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $txt_Mail = $row['txtMail'];
   $rxtMail = $row['rxtMail'];

   $to = $txt_Mail;  // want johnery99@gmail.com here only but not able to fetch  
   $subject = 'Hello Subject!';
   $message = 'Hi';
   $headers = 'From:'. $rxtMail .' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: '. $rxtMail .' . "\r\n" .        // want sarah88@gmail.com here but txt_email  does not give any value here means sarah88@gmail.com
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

}
```

next time, try to use mysqli (Mysql Improved) or PDO. mysql functions is deprecated and for the future it wont be supported anymore

Comment: Yes the code is excellent this is what I want but please check these line  $headers = 'From: $txt_email' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: txt_email' . "\r\n" .         these line do notgive me from: johnery99@gmail.com     like but first one give me correct value to:sarah88@gmail.com

Comment: on console this is showing From: $txt_email
Reply-To: $txt_email

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$txt_username = mysql_real_escape_string($txt_username);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT txt_email,rxt_email FROM DriveRegisterTable WHERE txt_username ='$txt_username'");

//use loop if you are expecting more than 1 rows, otherwise remove loop
// and just use $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $email1 = $row['txt_email'];
     $email2 = $row['rxt_email'];

     //code to send email to those 2 emails
}
```

Note that I added `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape your variable. Dont just plug into your query it is vulnerable to `SQL Injection`.

I would suggest looking at **PDO** or **MySQLi** prepared statements.

Comment: how to write email1 here instead of txtMail $headers = 'From: $row["txt_email"]' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: txt_email' . "\r\n" .      This line not give me correct value